# What is the probability that mouse with reach state A before state B

Tags: probability, markov-chains

[image]

I have a maze as shown above(use the link) and state 3 contains prize while state 7 contains shock. a mouse can be placed in any state from 1 to 9 randomly and it move through the maze uniformly at random

$P_i$ denote the probability that mouse reaches state 3 before state 7, given that AIM started in compartment i.

how to compute $P_i$ for $i ∈ \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Comment: You know this is a question about markov chains. What have you tried? Can you think of what states to have? And what your transition matrix should be? Can you think of a way to simplify the problem to only have 5 states? Can you think of the relevant ideas from markov chains that apply to the problem of “reach X before Y”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use general Markov chain tools for this, as the other answer suggests -- but you can also just wing it:

- Starting in 1, 5, or 9, you can get the answer immediately by symmetry considerations.
- Starting in 3 or 7, the game is over before it starts, so the probability is 100% of one, respective the other.
- Finally, if you start in 2, 4, 6, or 8, after *one step* you will be in a state that you now already know the probability for. So you just need an appropriately weighted average of those probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a set of linear equation linking the $P_i$s together and use the fact that $P_3 = 1$ and $P_7 = 0$

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example for one of the linear equation. I am a new to Markov Chain and do not have much knowledge about it